# Cygwin bash script removing equal sign

Tags: bash, makefile, cygwin

Cygwin make script is removing equals sign from command call. How do I escape it so that = is sent to command.

Tried escaping = with \ and enclosing it with "" and '' but it did not work.

$(elabcmd) = $(XELAB_DEFAULT) \
    -generic VERSION=10

compile:
    $(elabcmd)

Here is the result:

cygwin prompt:> make compile
Running: xelab.exe -generic VERSION 10

(note that the equal sign is not there)

I want
xelab.exe -generic VERSION=10

Comment: You will need to escape it from both 'make' and 'bash'.

Comment: Could you please suggest how to do so? This same script works correctly with Linux make and bash. It does not work only with Cygwin.

Comment: First I would check that scripts have LF end-of-line. Cygwin git will preserve eol. Win git will add CR by default. Some win versions of tar add CR to text files. Make sure you are running cygwin make. (--version). Make sure you are running cygwin bash, not WSL bash. Are cygwin dirs ahead of all win dirs in PATH?

Answer (score 0):

This bit:

`$(elabcmd) = $(XELAB_DEFAULT) \
-generic VERSION=10`

doesn't make sense to me. Shouldn't this be `elabcmd = ...`, not `$(elabcmd) = ...`?

I created the following Makefile according to your specifications:

```
XELAB_DEFAULT = true.exe
elabcmd = $(XELAB_DEFAULT) -generic VERSION=10

compile:
      $(elabcmd)
```

Then ran it in Cygwin:

`$ make compile`

Output:

`true.exe -generic VERSION=10`

Looks like it works to me.